# Writing c++ without new and delete keyword? Best approach?

Tags: c++, containers

I'm trying to write c++ code without using the keywords `new` and `delete`.

First, is it a good practice or not ?

One of the side effects of coding like this is that I can't rely on `nullptr`for empty values.

For instance:

`std::array<std::array<fb::Block *, Panel::Y>, Panel::X> blocks;`

becomes

`std::array<std::array<fb::Block, Panel::Y>, Panel::X> blocks;`

What is the best way to describe an empty Block ?

I though about using this:

```
class Block {
  private:
  protected:
  public:
  ...
  static const Block EMPTY;
  };
}

const Block EMPTY(0, BlockType::TUTORIAL, 0, 0);
```

What do you guys think ? Is this a good approach ?

Comment: Or use `unique_ptr` with an hand written `make_unique`.

Comment: I don't think that avoiding pointers entirely is necessarily a good idea. I think a better idea is to learn to use smart pointers (`std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr` etc).

Comment: `is it a good practice or not` No. Then again, using pointers solely to give yourself `optional` semantics is not good practice either.

Comment: Look into the Null Object Pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) if you want to return "empty" values.  Or for containers, simply return empty containers.

Comment: Null Object is terrible.

Comment: Good point, i'm going to try smart pointers. Anyone mind adapting this code to smart pointers just as an example ?

Comment: Are you avoiding those two keywords, or are you avoiding pointers?  Or the heap entirely?

Comment: No, just the keywords, i'm find with smart pointers and heap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write safe code and simplify memory management, you should indeed avoid the `delete`. But there is no need to discard the `new`. The best way to go is to allocate any object you want with `new` and store it in smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`. You can always compare those pointers with `nullptr`. And all objects will be automatically deleted.

Some will advise to replace raw `new` with `make_shared` and `make_unique` calls in this scenario.

The related question is when to use `T&` and when to use `T*` for passing an argument to a function. The rule of thumb is: use `T*` whenever an input argument can be absent, use `T&` to ensure an input argument is provided.

Comment: I think that's what i'm looking for. Any pointers to any tutorial, samples, etc. ?

Comment: Don't know of really good tutorial, can only suggest classic books on C++. Try MSDN as a starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh279669.aspx. And if you like the answer, accept it.

Comment: For everything with C, my first stop is http://www.lysator.liu.se/c. Has lots of pointers to good resources (a bit scanty on C++).

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a language designed for maximum performance while offering very high level features (full OO, multiple inheritance, generic programming). Part of the "maximum performance" is precisely use of explicit memory management (yes, there are languages, and even packages for C++ like the [Boehm collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector), that lighten your burden of keeping track of allocated memory; the cost is huge and sometimes prohibitive). C++ is a *tool*, which happens to have *very* sharp edges. Keep out of the hands of children. Use with extreme care.

The features of the language are included to be *used* when and where appropiate.

Comment: I know, I'm just new to "new c++", I used to code in c++ 10 years ago, then did some Java at work, and now I rediscover the c++ with a shitloads of new exciting stuff. I just want to masterize these tools and this is why I ask for guidance.

Comment: Just use the features with taste. One of the problems with large/complex languages like C++ is the temptation to overuse features, or combine them badly.

Comment: Having good taste requires a bit af tasting upfront, and i don't have this experience yet. Hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

> One of the side effects of coding like this is that I can't rely on
>   nullptr for empty values.

What on earth are you on about? `nullptr` makes a fine empty pointer, no matter where that pointer was supposed to point to. It has nothing, whatsoever, to do with `new` and `delete`. Not `new`ing anything doesn't stop you from using pointers, empty or not.

> First, is it a good practice or not ?

Both `new` and `delete` are horrifically unsafe, so it's quite fine to drive them from your codebase like the infectious plague of bugs that they are. It is absolutely true that you should never, ever, use `delete`. `new` is *slightly* more complex, as there's more justification for some kinds of very thin wrappers, like

```
template<typename T, typename... Args> std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

However, it's *absolutely* true that outside of wrappers specifically intended to allocate for smart pointers, you should never use non-placement `new`, and you should never use `delete` or `delete[]`. Use RAII classes like smart pointers and containers which can safely guarantee the correctness of your program.

Comment: Oh because "never use `delete` or `delete[]`" is never going to be _horribly misinterpreted_ by casually passing readers

Comment: Better that than the alternative.

Comment: Well, either they can avoid `delete` and `delete[]` completely and use smart pointers all the time and then maybe run into one case in five years where using them would be justified- if that- or they could write ten thousand bugs in five years using manual management. What negative side effect do you even imagine from following that rule?

Comment: Also your first response doesn't seem valid. Sure, using pointers for nullability doesn't directly correspond with `new`/`delete`, but it _is_ coupled to dynamic allocation since the user is not going to want to store pointers to local objects.

Comment: I'm imagining a slew of programs with memory leaks when someone starts spreading the rumour that we should never use `delete` in C++ without comprehending the true meaning of what you're saying. "Because an expert on that stackoverflow chat forum said `delete` is bad"

Comment: @Lightness: What's wrong with pointers to local objects? They're plenty useful. Also, I suddenly see what you're saying, but I also clearly state to use smart pointers and containers, so I'm not sure that you could reasonably misinterpret this.

Comment: I like to think that _I_ couldn't, but that's not what I'm talking about ;)

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of memory management and i currently heavily rely on new and delete keywords without a single memory leak. I just want to enforce it even stronger.

Comment: Then use containers/smart pointers exclusively, and definitely erase `delete` from your codebase.